# Iterate over JSON and add the list array into the object/array

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have these two `JSON` arrays:

```
{ 
  "Person": {
    "Info": [
      "name": "Becky",
      "age": 14
    ]
   },
  "Fruits": [
    {
      "name": "avocado",
      "organic": true
    },
    {
      "name": "mango",
      "organic": true
    }
  ],
  "Vegetables": [
    {
      "name": "brocoli",
      "organic": true
    },
    {
      "name": "lettuce",
      "organic": true
    }
  ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is to use `Jackson` and `Gson` libraries to make everything look pretty.

Something like this. This works fine with `Gson`. So the output I want is:

```
{ 
  "Person": {
    "Info": [
      "name":"Becky",
      "age": 14
    ]
  },
  "FruitsList": {
    "Fruits": [
      {
        "name": "avocado",
        "organic": true
      },
      {
        "name": "mango",
        "organic": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "VegetablesList": {
    "Vegetables": [
      {
        "name": "brocoli",
        "organic": true
      },
      {
        "name": "lettuce",
        "organic": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have set my classes as:

```
class Person{
   private List<Info> InfoList;
   //Set and get were set
}

class Info{
   private String name;
   private int age;
   //Set and get were set
}

class Fruits{
   private String name;
   private boolean organic;
   //Set and get were set
   public String toString(){
            return "Fruits:{" +
            "name:'" + name+ '\'' +
            ", organic:" + organic+'\''+
            '}';
   }
 }

 class Vegetables{
   private String name;
   private boolean;
   //Set and get were set
   public String toString(){
            return "Fruits:[" +
            "name:'" + name+ '\'' +
            ", organic:" + organic+'\''+
            ']';
   }
 }

class rootFinal{
    private List<Fruits> fruitList;
    private List<Vegetables> vegetablesList;
    private List<Person> personList;
    //Set and get were set
}

class mainJson{
   final InputStream fileData = ..("testPVF.json");

   ObjectMapper map = new Ob..();
   rootFinal root = map.readValue(fileData,rootFinal.class);
   // I can access each class with 
   System.out.printl(root.getHeaderList.get(0));
}
```

This outputs...

```
[Fruit{name:'avocado', organic:true}, Fruit{name:'mango', organic:true}]
```

But this is not what I want.

I am trying to do an iteration over the JSON file or somehow if there is a better way to check an array exists. Add additional object/array to it.

If I find `Veg` or `Fruit` I want to somehow add `VegList` and `FruitList` as shown. It should ignore the `"Person": {}` since it's in a `{}` symbol.

Is there a way to do this with `Gson`?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to wrap every `JSON Array` node using `JSON Object` node. To do this, you do not need to use `POJO` model, you can read `JSON` payload as `ObjectNode` and use it's `API` to update it.

### Jackson

Simple example with `Jackson` library:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonObjectApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jsonFile);

        Map<String, JsonNode> valuesToAdd = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        // create fields iterator
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = root.fields();
        while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = fieldsIterator.next();

            // if entry represents array
            if (entry.getValue().isArray()) {
                // create wrapper object
                ObjectNode arrayWrapper = mapper.getNodeFactory().objectNode();
                arrayWrapper.set(entry.getKey(), root.get(entry.getKey()));

                valuesToAdd.put(entry.getKey(), arrayWrapper);

                // remove it from object.
                fieldsIterator.remove();
            }
        }

        valuesToAdd.forEach((k, v) -> root.set(k + "List", v));

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(root));
    }
}
```

Above code prints for your `JSON`:

```
{
  "Person" : {
    "Info" : [ {
      "name" : "Becky",
      "age" : 14
    } ]
  },
  "FruitsList" : {
    "Fruits" : [ {
      "name" : "avocado",
      "organic" : true
    }, {
      "name" : "mango",
      "organic" : true
    } ]
  },
  "VegetablesList" : {
    "Vegetables" : [ {
      "name" : "brocoli",
      "organic" : true
    }, {
      "name" : "lettuce",
      "organic" : true
    } ]
  }
}
```

### Gson

Very similar solution we could implement with `Gson` library:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();

        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(jsonFile)) {
            JsonObject root = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);

            Map<String, JsonElement> valuesToAdd = new LinkedHashMap<>();

            // create fields iterator
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> fieldsIterator = root.entrySet().iterator();
            while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = fieldsIterator.next();
                // if entry represents array
                if (entry.getValue().isJsonArray()) {
                    // create wrapper object
                    JsonObject arrayWrapper = new JsonObject();
                    arrayWrapper.add(entry.getKey(), root.get(entry.getKey()));

                    valuesToAdd.put(entry.getKey(), arrayWrapper);

                    // remove it from object.
                    fieldsIterator.remove();
                }
            }

            valuesToAdd.forEach((k, v) -> root.add(k + "List", v));

            System.out.println(gson.toJson(root));
        }
    }
}
```

Output is the same.

Comment: This is great! Thank you! This is very much simple than I was doing. I was hard coding this.

Comment: Reputation is not high. Sorry. Just started using this. Sorry.

Comment: How would you do this with GSON? Is there a way to do this with GSON?

Answer (score 0):

Check [Get Pretty Printer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter())

Also check [specific APIs for Pretty Printing](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html)

Sample Code:

```js
//This example is using Input as JSONNode
//One can serialize POJOs to JSONNode using ObjectMapper.
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(
     inputNode)
```